# When to assert a 'Same Individual As' property to an individual in Protege?

Tags: ontology, protege

I am new to Ontologies, so I apologize if seems like a very naive question.

For example, I have a class named 'PersonalInformation' and a subClass within it called 'Name'. PersonalInformation as an individual named 'Name' and Name (class) has individuals: 'FirstName', 'MiddleName', and 'LastName'. Do I set the 'Same Indidividual As' property as for Name (individual) as FirstName, MiddleName, and LastName, since they are all in essence names?

How do I set this up, and when is it appropriate to use the 'Same Individual As' property?

Answer (score 0):

It is appropriate to assign the 'Same Individual As' axiom, when two individuals are named differently, but refer to one and the same instance. You could for example have one individual named after your real name and one named after your nickname. Both individuals describe the same person (and they would probably be an instance of a class called 'Person').

Now concerning your question, I wouldn't even use individuals, but model everything as classes, because they all describe a set of potential individuals. For example FirstName is a class that could contain individuals like 'Peter', 'George', 'Anna', etc.